# to pass value of a variable in one function to another using session

Tags: php

I have a class Blocka_Model (actually a MODEL in KOhana framework) with 2 functions input() and output().The function input is called from a function wriiten inside a controller called Home_Controller and it passes an argument to the function input. Now I want that argument passed to input() function to be accessible in the function output(). Both the functions input() and output() are inside Model class Blocka_Model.  I want to get that argument $val from input() to output)

```
class Blocka_Model extends Block_Model {

    protected $tablname = 'moves';

    public function input($val) {  ...  } 

    public function output() {  ...  }

}
```

Comment: Your code's formatting is... not right. Is there something missing? Why are there so many spaces and line breaks?

Comment: i just wrote 2 functions only, i require $val to be accessible in output() function using sessions

Comment: I tried to edit it so it was properly formatted, but I'm not real sure what it represents. The `output()` method appears to belong to an object, but does not fall within the Blocka_Model class.

Comment: both input and output functions r inside same class Blocka_Model

Comment: I edited by taking all the extra spaces and line breaks out. Is `output()` part of Blocka_Model class?

Comment: the class should be closed after output function, sorry i did not close the class properly

Comment: Yes  output() Is  part of Blocka_Model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your title says you wish to use a `session`:

```
class Blocka_Model extends Block_Model {

    protected $session_unique_id;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->session_unique_id = uniqid();
    }

    /*
     * Save $val in our current session
     */
    public function input($val) {
        $_SESSION[get_class($this).$this->session_unique_id] = $val;
    } 

    /*
     * Check for a value in our session
     *  - if it is set, return it
     *  - else return null
     */
    public function output() {   
        return isset($_SESSION[get_class($this).$this->session_unique_id]) ? 
                     $_SESSION[get_class($this).$this->session_unique_id] : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Totally missed the `$_SESSION` part.

Comment: The OP left this as a comment on my session-less answer: *but this i tried but it somehow does not work here, actually there r many functions and differnt classses, Its actually aframework so would like to make that value $val a session variable , it $ val is posted inside a function getposted() function inside a class Home_COntroller*

Comment: let me try and see, I am trying with sesison since other usual methods did not work,Thanks

Comment: What would prevent one class instance from returning the value left by another class instance?

Comment: In the constructor, you could give each class a random private variable value and use that as the key.

Comment: but err0r "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()"

Comment: [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)? There are so many functions I've never heard of in PHP... :D

Comment: with  session i am able to pass variable value to output function, but i had to delete session_start(); that's all

Comment: @Jared Farrish thanks for the tip :) Re: PHP's functions -  same!